# Using restangular with Parse.com (getList with parameters)

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, restangular

I'm starting with Restangular and Parse.com for a small webapp. I can create objects and get them with the Id.
When I try to get with parameters, I have the following problem: I obtain all rows in my table.

Here is my code:

```
Restangular.all('VinDetail').getList({
producer: "Parigot"}).then(
function(test) { 
vin.test = test;
});
```

Then i get this url in chrome dev tools:
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/VinDetail?producer=Parigot

And here is my result:

```
{"results":[{"producer":"Parigot Père et Fils","createdAt":"2014-08-06T21:09:47.317Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-06T21:10:19.362Z","objectId":"SGPqVsIw81"},{"producer":"Parigot","manufacturer":"sur place","notes":"test note","price":8,"createdAt":"2014-08-08T05:36:08.578Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-08T05:36:08.578Z","objectId":"JbWf2Ma5Pb"},{"createdAt":"2014-08-08T05:40:43.993Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-08T05:40:43.993Z","objectId":"I8bat0qZNq"},{"createdAt":"2014-08-08T05:48:02.328Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-08T05:48:02.328Z","objectId":"b3bQKWVPDO"}]}
```

But i would like only the second record.

Do you see what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,

bevrard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem to get the second record. With the API of Parse.com I need to add a 'where : ' for the parameters.

Like this:
Restangular.all('VinDetail').getList(
{
where :
{ 
producer: "Parigot"
}
});